# How to Change Colors based on Airline in Plotly US Flight Maps Example

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

In plotly's sample gallery they provide the following code to create a map showing US flight patterns in a given month:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd

df_airports = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_us_airport_traffic.csv')
df_airports.head()

df_flight_paths = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv')
df_flight_paths.head()

airports = [ dict(
    type = 'scattergeo',
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    lon = df_airports['long'],
    lat = df_airports['lat'],
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    text = df_airports['airport'],
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = dict( 
        size=2, 
        color='rgb(255, 0, 0)',
        line = dict(
            width=3,
            color='rgba(68, 68, 68, 0)'
        )
    ))]

flight_paths = []
for i in range( len( df_flight_paths ) ):
flight_paths.append(
    dict(
        type = 'scattergeo',
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = [ df_flight_paths['start_lon'][i], df_flight_paths['end_lon'][i] ],
        lat = [ df_flight_paths['start_lat'][i], df_flight_paths['end_lat'][i] ],
        mode = 'lines',
        line = dict(
            width = 1,
            color = 'red',
        ),
        opacity = float(df_flight_paths['cnt'][i])/float(df_flight_paths['cnt'].max()),
    )
)

layout = dict(
    title = 'Feb. 2011 American Airline flight paths<br>(Hover for airport names)',
    showlegend = False, 
    geo = dict(
        scope='north america',
        projection=dict( type='azimuthal equal area' ),
        showland = True,
        landcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
        countrycolor = 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    ),
)

fig = dict( data=flight_paths + airports, layout=layout )
py.iplot( fig, filename='d3-flight-paths' )
```

If you view the source data for the flight paths provided [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv) you'll notice that the data actually provides the airline as well.

My questions is this - What would be the simplest way to change the color of the lines based on which airline provided the flight? For example AA is in red, but Delta is in blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review, because each line is being added iteratively in a loop, it is a pretty easy fix. By just adding in an if / else statement and assigning the color to a variable as shown below, I was able to achieve the desired result:

```
for i in range( len( my_df ) ):
    if my_df['Current Location?'][i] == 'Yes':
        flight_color = 'blue'
    else:
        flight_color = 'red'
    flight_paths.append(
        dict(
            type = 'scattergeo',
            locationmode = 'country names',
            lon = [ my_df['Longitude'][i], -98.5795],
            lat = [ my_df['Latitude'][i], 39.8283],
            mode = 'lines',
            line = dict(
                width = 2,
                color = flight_color,
            ),
            opacity = float(my_df['Passengers'][i])/float(my_df['Passengers'].max()),
        )
    )
```